# Length mismatch: Expected axis has 102 elements, new values have 4 elements

Tags: python

Below is the code

```
new_values = pd.DataFrame(new_values)
new_values.columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

data['Years'] = new_values['a'].astype(str) + " " + new_values['b'].astype(str) + " " + new_values['c'].astype(str)+ " " + new_values['d'].astype(str)
```

I get this error - `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 102 elements, new values have 4 elements`
I want to keep only first four columns. How do I modify this code ?

```
min = data['Contract Start Year'].min()
max = data['Contract End Year'].max() + 1
max = int(max)
unique_values = (range(min,max))
new_values = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    start = int(data.loc[i, ['Contract Start Year']])
    try:
        end = int(data.loc[i, ['Contract End Year']]) + 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Handling the error")
    else:
        print("No error here")
    new_values.append(list(range(start, end)))
    new_values = pd.DataFrame(new_values)
    new_values.columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to transpose your dataframe first. `new_values` is probably a list of 4 items each containing 102 items:

```
new_values = pd.DataFrame(new_values).T  # <- HERE
new_values.columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Tried but the error still persists. In case it is a problem with 102 columns, can you help me with a modification that only keeps first four columns ?

Comment: I need more information: what is new_values?

Comment: Can you share your data (or provide minimal sample to reproduce the problem) and explain what the code does?